# UIPicker and send selected row data to UIView

Tags: iphone

I have written a UIPicker which is populated from a .plist. This part works fine.
What I don't know how do is once the row has been selected is to display that underlying data in another UIView.

The code in my .m file is:

```
    #import "airlinePickerViewController.h"


@implementation airlinePickerViewController

@synthesize picker;
@synthesize airlines;
@synthesize airline;
@synthesize teleno;



- (IBAction)butonPressed:(id)sender
{
 NSInteger airRow = [picker selectedRowInComponent:kAirlineComponent];
 NSInteger telRow = [picker selectedRowInComponent:kTelenoComponent];

 NSString *air = [self.airline objectAtIndex:airRow];
 NSString *tel = [self.teleno objectAtIndex:telRow];

 NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You selected  %@.", tel];
 NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ is in %@", tel, air];

 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];
 [title release];
 [message release];
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
  // Initialization code
 }
 return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

 NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"airlinedictionary" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
 self.airlines = dictionary;
 [dictionary release];

 NSArray *components = [self.airlines allKeys];
 NSArray *sorted = [components sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
 self.airline = sorted;

 NSString *selectedAirline = [self.airline objectAtIndex:0];
 NSArray *array = [airlines objectForKey:selectedAirline];
 self.teleno = array;
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
 // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc { 
 [picker release];
 [airlines release];
 [airline release];
 [teleno release];
 [super dealloc];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
 return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 if (component == kAirlineComponent)
  return [self.airline count];
 return [self.teleno count];
}
#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 if (component == kAirlineComponent)
  return [self.airline objectAtIndex:row];
 return [self.teleno objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 if (component == kAirlineComponent)
 {
  NSString *selectedAirline = [self.airline objectAtIndex:row];
  NSArray *array = [airlines objectForKey:selectedAirline];
  self.teleno = array;
  [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:kTelenoComponent animated:YES];
  [picker reloadComponent:kTelenoComponent];
 }
}
@end
```

Can anyone help me get to grips with how to complete this task.

Many thanks

Dereck

Answer (score 0):

Now a somehow general answer:
I assume you want to switch to a completely new View (not a subview) so the first thing you probably need is a Navigation Controller or TabBarController to facilitate pushing / switching to new Views. Before switching / pushing the new View you could assign the selected values as properties to that new View after initialization but before switching to the new View.